# In Excel PivotTables, how do I show items that occur in one category but not another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, powerpivot

Simplified version of my data:

`item   category    number
apples  fruit        7
orange  fruit        2
tomato  fruit        3
tomato  vege         9
zuchini vege         2
tomato  vege        17
onion   vege         1`

With a PivotTable in Excel 2010, is there a way for me to set it up so I get a list of items that appear in the vege category but not in the fruit category? The output in this example would be:

`zuchini
onion`

(it would not contain tomato since that also appears in the fruit category). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this with a pivot table as the filtering is not that advanced on the grouped items.  Or at least it isn't that automated.

I was able to do this with an SQL query.  You can query Excel from Excel using MS Query and a data connection (simply point the datasource to the file you are working on).

Here is the final result:
[image: MS Query Results]

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT `Sheet1$`.category, `Sheet1$`.item, `Sheet1$`.number
FROM `C:\Admin\StackExchange\sql on excel.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
WHERE `Sheet1$`.item NOT IN 
(SELECT `Sheet1$`.item
FROM `C:\Admin\StackExchange\sql on excel.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$` 
WHERE (`Sheet1$`.category<>'vege'))
AND `Sheet1$`.category='vege'
```

Let me know if you need more help setting up the data connection.

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I'm looking into how to setup a data connection and use the table as the data to try to get your example query working.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can start a Query from an Excel Table.

I would start one Query called Fruit, and Filter on category = fruit.  Then I would start another Query called Vege, and Filter on category = vege. Then in the Vege Query I would add a Merge command to join to the Fruit query using the Item columns, keeping rows that don't match.  Then I would use the Expand command to add a column from the Fruit query e.g. Item.  Then I would Filter on that new column, keeping only the Null rows.

Here's a starter on Power Query Merge and Expand:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/merge-queries-HA104149757.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

Comment: Thanks, I looked into this, and it was helpful to know. Wish I could mark multiple accepted answers!

Answer (score -1):

To answer this Question, first let's look at the typical pivot table. There's the table generated from the data and there's the pivot table field list.  To do what you are asking go to the pivot table field list and where you see category place the cursor over that then you will see a small upside down triangle the right.  Click on the triangle.  This will open up a pane with Filter options. In the bottom of the pane click the top box effectively unchecking all of them, then search for the one you want... in this case that would be clicking the zucchini and onion.

Hope this helps and have fun!

Comment: Thanks, but what I was asking was for how to get Excel to come up with that based on a query.

Comment: How are you linking to the excel table from Access or some other database where by you are writing sql code?  The reason I ask is that queries aren't native to Excel.